# Excel VBA - how to prevent a user changing worksheets conditional on certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm currently creating a workbook which has an input tab, all of it's data flowing through into later tabs. I want to prevent a user from moving onto any other tabs until all of the relavent information is filled in on the input sheet.

I'm currently trying to use the workbook_sheetactivate event but have spent a lot of time going between this and worksheet_change event, neither of which I can get working properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a form instead.  Otherwise, hide all of the sheets except for the one that they have to complete.  Use a button (or 2) to move between the sheets.  That way, you can keep all of your "are you allowed to move to the next sheet" logic wrapped up in a button (or other sub).

Comment: Using a custom form would be the best way to do this as you can set the Modal of the form so that the user is not able to select anything in excel until you have closed the form. You can then set the conditions so that the form can only be closed once all the fields are completed.

Alternatively, you can put code in the other sheets so that they check for a condition on another sheet (input tab) and if the condition isn't met then make the input tab active again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use forms then I would suggest adding code similar to the following to each sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Obviously you will need to change the sheet names, range and value but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: this worked brilliantly, obviously what I wanted to do was a bit more complicated than I explained here but this provided me the one step I was missing. Thanks a lot!